# How to send a React-native Post request (ImagePicker) to API in C # .Net Core

Tags: c#, react-native, .net-core, upload, axios

I've done a post method using Axios to upload images using ImagePicker in React-Native but when I send this request to the API Post with my FormData it appears to me the 400 error

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Request failed
>   with status code 400

But when I use the Upload variable instead of the FormData I created it sends the request to my API but no data

[image: Client - Side]

[image: Server - Side]

I already used the post method to log in and it works with password and user enter the API and I get the right values

```
const response = await api.post("Usuarios/FindByEmailSenha", {
      email: this.state.email,
      pass: this.state.pass
    });
```

**Client Side**

```
handledUpload = () => {
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({}, async upload => {
        const arquivo = new FormData();

        arquivo.append('file', {
          uri: upload.uri,
          type:upload.type,
          name: upload.fileName
        });

        var fotos = {
          Id: 1,
          IdUsuario: 1,
          NumCode: 4
      }

      api.post(`galeria/UploadArquivos/`, arquivo, fotos);

    })
  };`
```

**Server Side**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadArquivos")]
[Consumes("application/json", "application/json-patch+json", "multipart/form-data")]
public IEnumerable<Galeria> UploadArquivos(IFormFileCollection arquivo, Galeria fotos)
{

}
```

I hope to receive FormData data sent from React-Native to my API so I can debug and be saving on the server

Comment: did you find the solution?